# Type conversion between nvarchar and datetime when migrating data with "Generate Scripts..."

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, nvarchar

I'm copying data from a SQLServer2012 database to a SQLServer2014 database using `Tasks>>Generate scripts...` and selecting `Data only` in the Advanced Options.

The problem appears when I try to execute the resulting script in the SQLServer2014 database. The error is:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range

I know that's probably because the databases have different cultures and the inserts which the first server are generating:

```
INSERT [dbo].[CollectionSet] ([Id], [CreationDate], [Active], [MenuOrder]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2015-09-18 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1, 1)
```

do not work in the second server.

So, my question is: How can I generate a script with the correct date format so it can work on the second server?

PD: I have no access to Management Studio on the destination server.

Comment: You can save the generated SSIS package, then edit it in SSDT to perform the required transformations.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question, I thought, you are using the database migration tools (like the export/import wizard). Try to create a view which contains the transformed data, then generate the insert script using that view.

Comment: I have more than 40 tables. I could create 40 views, but i was hoping for something easier.

Comment: On the destination server: Right click on the database -> Tasks -> Import Data... -> Configure the package with the wizard (data source, mappings, etc) -> Execute/Save as you wish.

Comment: @Pred Sorry, but I have no access to the Management Studio on the destination server. I need to do it using sqlcmd. That's why I need the script. I have edited my question to include that information.

Comment: You can run management studio on your desktop, it don't have to run on the destination server.

Comment: I did solve the problem from the "Export..." window. I did the mapping from there. Thank's for your help!

Comment: Anyway, the question is still in the air. Is there a way to make a format conversion and generate the scripts correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I can recall it correctly (fixme?) the Generate Scripts SSMS feature will not allow to do any transformation and it assumes that the destination where you want to execute the output has the same (or at least compatible) configuration (collation, table structure, etc).

Here are some solutions/workarounds (*braindump*):

**ETL Tool (SSIS for example)**

Your best bet is to use an ETL tool such as SSIS (shipped with SQL Server Standard and above) to extract-transorm-load your data across servers.

You can generate SSIS Packages by using the Import / Export wizard(s) (under `Tasks` in the database context menu).

**Using backups**

You can always create a database backup on the source server, then restore it on the destination server. To migrate the data into the new database, you can use regular SQL queries.

**Workarounds**

- Create a view on the problematic table and transform the problematic column in the view, then export the view.
- Build a view on the destination server (with transformations), insert into that view.

**In my opinion**, the most flexible solution is to use an ETL tool, like SSIS, create the packages and execute them.

As a last thought: Most probably you can't solve this problem without investing some time in it (like write queries manually for each problematic tables, or to build/edit SSIS packages).

Comment: As I said in previous comments, the view creation is not a good solution, because I have a lot of tables to migrate. The backup is not an option, because can't restore a backup from 2012 to 2014 versions. So I've solved the problem using SSIS, exporting and doing some magic with the mapping set.

Comment: Good job! I know you mentioned what you can't do, but it could be useful info for further readers, this is why I've added it.

Comment: I know, thank you. I was just making a resume of my experience. Could be useful to somebody too :)

Comment: Actually a comment: it should be possible to restore a SQL Server 2012 backup on SQL Server 2014 - Assuming, that the edition (Standard, Enterprise, etc) are the same or higher on the destination. (However restoring a 2014 backup on 2012 will not work - fixme?)